# Getting Powershell command history (or current) from memory

Tags: powershell, memory, dump, freeze, powershell-cmdlet

If I have a Powershell script running right know, does someone know how can I get the current running code/history of commands, through the dump of the running process (using Task Manager)?

I know I can get it by strings, and I've tried even getting a minidump (using Process Explorer) and analyzing it with multiple programs, but it doesn't give me the relevant information (Mostly models, handles and general information).

Moreover, if someone can find me a structure for dmp files, to parse it with code, I'll be very thankful.

Thanks.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I'm trying to understand what my clients are running on their workstations.

Comment: Depending on how "up-to-date" these clients are, a better solution would be to [turn on automatic transcripts](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2015/06/09/powershell-the-blue-team/)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Looks good. Do you know about more solutions? What if I want to work live, without pre-configuration?